# Как сделать кнопку рандома на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здраствуйте, хочу сделать кнопку на сайте при нажатии на которую открывалась случайная html страница из списка. Может кто-нибудь подсказать?

Написал такой скрипт:

```
const page = document.querySelector('Random');
var links = ['01.html','02.html'];

page.onclick = function() {
page.location.href = links[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
}
```

Comment: Вот как можно получать случайный элемент массива - https://expange.ru/e/Случайный_элемент_массива_(JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Твой скрипт имеет ошибку.

Необходимо файл, на котором находится кнопка с классом "Random", поместить в тег  с атрибутом href, который будет указывать путь к файлу (01.html, 02.html и т.д.).

Попробуй исправить скрипт следующим образом:

```html
<a href="#" class="Random">Нажми меня</a>
```

```js
const page = document.querySelector('.Random');
const links = ['01.html','02.html'];

page.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
};
```

Как ты можешь заметить, мы изменили выбор случайной страницы и исправили ошибки в синтаксисе. Теперь код должен работать. При нажатии на кнопку ссылка будет выбираться случайным образом из списка и открываться в текущей вкладке.

Надеюсь, это поможет тебе реализовать функционал на твоем сайте!

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а что не так собственно? Кнопка есть, событие есть, рандом есть. Всё как просил человек. Я всё проверил на codepen

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, теперь разобрался

Comment: @ВячеславИльинский, если написанное по приведённой ссылке осталось непонятым, то вот ещё [обсужение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/178576).